# Creating Unix script to sleep better

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I know that I try to work to late in the night and that at this time I'm absolutely unproductive, I work for 5 minutes then switch to a link seen on youtube, then come back to my work, waste some more time on he internet... until 2 in the morning, hour at which I am able to discplinate myself and go to bed.

How could I write a script that automatically shuts down the computer at midnight?

I think I have to use the command `crontab` and write the following command in it

```
shutdown 00:00
```

I'm asking you if what I do is right, first and optimal or if it exists other ways to do it.

Here is what I made

```
myComputer:~$ crontab -l
# m h  dom mon dow   command
 55 23 *   *   *     /home/Marine1/soundOfSilence
 00 00 *   *   *     shutdown
```

Here is what is within `/home/Marine1/soundOfSilence`

```
#!/bin/bash

mpg123 /path/to/short/sound.mp3
shutdown 5
```

Comment: connect the server to a relay, and shutdown down your lights till 7AM ;)

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I don't understand the joke... I'm not native... :/ :'(

Comment: half truth, half joke...http://www.aliexpress.com/item/2-two-channel-relay-module-relay-expansion-board-with-optocoupler-3-3V-and-5V-compatible/32306640604.html Electrical relays, they can be commanded to turn on/off lights or electrical appliances. I have one connected to my "Raspberry"-like device.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest doing something a bit different. Your approach is fine, but might prove annoying, when you got to do something sometime late and PC shuts down in the middle of the work. Instead, I'd suggest that you write a simple script that does something to bring your attention few minutes before shutdown, so you can prepare yourself.

The simplest approach would be to just run shutdown with 5 minute delay - it sends a warning. However, it might not be enough, and if you want to make sure that you notice it, you might do something more invasive, e.g. play some sound.

Example script would look more or less like this(I hope it's correct):

```
#!/bin/bash

mpg123 /path/to/short/sound.mp3
shutdown 5
```

mpg123 can be used to play audio MPEG. If you choose other format, you will need to change the command, but it should be easy enough to google.

Comment: That sounds great! But what would the script be then?

Comment: @Marine1 please see if I answered your question now.

Comment: I'm trying tonight and let you know if it worked!

Comment: I checked a bit:`Marine1:~$ /path/to/short/sound.mp3
bash: /path/to/short/sound.mp3: No such file or directory`
But I think I can change it to something I find in my laptop, isn't it?

Comment: @Marine1 well, the file should not exist. It was an example to show that you need to create a short sound in MPEG format, and then provide a full path to that location.

Comment: Okay, I loaded a true sound and tried to install `mpg123` yet, it answered me `Err http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe mpg123 amd64 1.16.0-1ubuntu1
  Could not connect to 192.168.1.254:3128 (192.168.1.254). - connect (113: No route to host)
E: Failed to fetch http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mpg123/mpg123_1.16.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb  Could not connect to 192.168.1.254:3128 (192.168.1.254). - connect (113: No route to host)

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`
I also tried with `play`, the answer ~ the same

Comment: @Marine1 Looks like you've got connection problem. If you can't do `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install XXX`, where XXX is any package, then I'd ask that as a separate question or google for answer. You might also want to try to find other player; I've only provided an example answer(and the one that works only for mp3 file); you might want to use other format, or other player(or both).